# Ubuntu 20.04 skype 8.64.0.67 не работает опция background effect Logitech C270 Webcam, раньше с Logitech Pro 920 камерой работало

Tags: linux, ubuntu, видео, skype

Купил новую видео камеру (недорогую) модель — `Logitech C270 Webcam`. При попытке использовать в Skype `Background effect` собственно отсутствует эта опция. То есть выглядит так:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

До этого с камерой Logitech Pro 920 все работало. Почему не работает сейчас? (гугл перегуглил, но подходящего решения не нашел...)

Comment: у меня было такое, просто приложение обновилось. Потом ещё раз обновилось и все стало хорошо.

Comment: @KoVadim Какая у вас версия?

Comment: вроде 8.65.0.76